# Safari 9 (in iOS9) ignores CSS settings

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, ios9

I am working on this web page: http://dev.mailagent.biz/cms/NEWS

It is responsive HTML that works fine in all browsers, all window sizes. It used to work fine on iPhones too, until iOS9 came to be. Now the whole site is broken. Extra margins (I am guessing) have been added, meaning all boxes appear to have a lot of white space. Below is a screenshot from my iPad.[image: iPad screenshot]

I set the viewport as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

I tried setting the margins to 0 and even to negative values, but the boxes don't move. I also tried removing any white spaces between div tags, with no change.

I am using a responsive css for all browsers: dev.mailagent.biz/cms/css/main_responsive.css
Then attaching this one specifically for iOS9: http://dev.mailagent.biz/cms/css/iOS9.css

However, most of the styles are still ignored, especially to do with margins. E.g. the iOS9 stylesheet should actually align the whole site to the left (.centeredWrapper has margin:0 not margin:auto). I know that the iOS9.css IS attached for iPhones/iPads, as e.g. some margins and colours were successfully changed in the menu across the top compared to the desktop version.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? How to I tell Safari to stop trying to be clever? Or how should I change my markup?

Comment: Check it out in Safari on a computer as well. Looks the same there and is probably easier to debug!

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of "Invalid CSS property declaration" warnings in Safari, which all seem related to *property selectors in two stylesheets. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: yes, since desktop safari upgraded to 9.0 it has the same problem. There is definitely problem with CSS validation as in the answer below. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a shrink-to-fit to your viewport tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Answer (score 2):

line 281 (or 98) in main_responsive seems to be the culprit:

```
.content ul, .content ol, :not(.content ul.slideshowUl) { margin: 0 0 10px 30px;}
```

I commented that out in the Safari inspector and the whole page went back to normal.

Comment: thanks and you are right, do you think the new Safari just doesn't like the :not statement?

Comment: Actually, with that comma in the statement, the :not selector appears to be selecting EVERYTHING on the page that does not have the class ".content ul.slideshowUL". In other words, not the correct syntax for what I assume it's trying to accomplish.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why Safari is the only one showing the issue!

Comment: Actually, Chrome app on iOS9 has the same issue. I assume it has something to do with the new rendering algorithm that Apple has implemented on their SDK level.